# Unable to load native hadoop library for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, hadoop, static-libraries

I am using Hadoop in Mac OS X. I think I installed Hadoop properly. When I tried to run an example WordCount problem, I got this error:

> INFO util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

From Googling this error, I learned that Hadoop Native Libraries are not supported in Mac OS.

Is there a way to load the Native Hadoop Library for Mac using some third-party software?

Comment: are you running hadoop 1.1.2 ? I have the same issue, however it is a warning and the job runs fine, I also have WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded ... Have you found a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)

Answer (score 4):

Run the example with an argument like this **-Djava.library.path**={YOUR_HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/ will probably fix the problem on the condition that Mac has something native under native directory

Comment: What is {YOUR_HADOOP_HOME}? is it my hadoop installed location?

Comment: @BalaSubramanyam Yes, {YOUR_HADOOP_HOME} corresponds to $HADOOP_HOME or %HADOOP_HOME%, depending on your system and whether you have those env vars set (assuming $HADOOP_HOME, since the question asked about Mac).