# ConnectException: Call From COMPUTER/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection

Tags: hadoop

I have recently installed the hadoop new version(2.2.0) on the Ubuntu 12.04LTS (64bit).

And testing the hadoop example dont work.

How to solve this problem????

`java.net.ConnectException: Call From ssel-PEGATRON/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

`at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:730)  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1351)  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:651)    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1679)    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1106)  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1397)     at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:278)  at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:354)     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)     at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:735)   at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:547)     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:642)  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2600(Client.java:314)     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1399)     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1318)  ... 33 more`

Comment: the problem was not caused by the warning of `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`, the real error is this one: `java.net.ConnectException: Call From ssel-PEGATRON/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;` try test the connections and turn off firewall

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos if you want to reslove the warning `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in the *hadoop-env.sh* and *yarn-env.sh*:

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=${HADOOP_PREFIX}/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_PREFIX/lib"
```