# Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Tags: java, hadoop

I have completed configured hadoop in Centos 6,64-bit using eclipse IDE, and created 3 classes of java like Mapper,Reducer and Driver.. but when I run my programme on hadoop it throws following exception:

```
14/04/28 15:03:39 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/04/28 15:03:39 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/04/28 15:03:39 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
```

I have checked this link too, 
[Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos)
but unfortunately I couldn't understand yet.

Comment: It's a warning and not an exception which can be ignored. I don't see any exception.

Comment: how can I ignore this warning?? or may I use my programme with this warning??

Answer (score 1):

As [Praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/614157/praveen-sripati) pointed out, this is a warning and not an exception. The reason for this warning is that the native library is compiled for 32bit by default. If you want to get rid of the warning, you have to compile hadoop from source on a 64bit system and use the resulting library. The binary can be found in `lib/native`.