# Why does ./bin/spark-shell give WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

On Mac OS X, I compiled Spark from the sources using the following command:

```
jacek:~/oss/spark
$ SPARK_HADOOP_VERSION=2.4.0 SPARK_YARN=true SPARK_HIVE=true SPARK_GANGLIA_LGPL=true xsbt
...

[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/jacek/oss/spark/)
> ; clean ; assembly
...
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/oss/spark/examples/target/scala-2.10/spark-examples-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.4.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 1964 s, completed May 9, 2014 5:07:45 AM
```

When I started `./bin/spark-shell` I noticed the following WARN message:

> WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your
>   platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

What might be the issue?

```
jacek:~/oss/spark
$ ./bin/spark-shell
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
14/05/09 21:11:17 INFO SecurityManager: Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
14/05/09 21:11:17 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: jacek
14/05/09 21:11:17 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(jacek)
14/05/09 21:11:17 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
...
14/05/09 21:11:49 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
...
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that there is such a library for OSX?

Comment: Nothing. I'm a mere end user who when noticed the warning have expected an answer to my and your questions. Is there such a library? Could I use it with Spark? Please guide/advise.

Comment: But then you're not asking a programming question, I submit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Supported Platforms](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html#Native_Hadoop_Library) of the Native Libraries Guide documentation in Apache Hadoop reads:

> The native hadoop library is supported on *nix platforms only. The
>   library does not to work with Cygwin or the Mac OS X platform.
>
> The native hadoop library is mainly used on the GNU/Linus platform and
>   has been tested on these distributions:
>
> - RHEL4/Fedora
> - Ubuntu
> - Gentoo
>
> On all the above distributions a 32/64 bit native hadoop library will work with a respective 32/64 bit jvm.

It appears that the WARN message should be disregarded on Mac OS X as the native library doesn't simply exist for the platform.

Comment: is it bad to have to use "builtin-java classes where applicable"? shall I put effort into installing hadoop native libraries (I am already on Linux)

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, if you `cd` into the `/sparkDir/conf` and rename the `spark-env.sh.template` to `spark-env.sh`, and then set the `JAVA_OPTS`and `hadoop_DIR`, it works.

You will also have to edit this `/etc/profile` line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: What would HADOOP_HOME be in the case where Hadoop isn't installed? (e.g. installed Spark directly from the Apache site but using it to submit jobs to a YARN-based Hadoop cluster remotely (EMR))

Comment: This fixes the problem, but why?