# Why does compression in YARN slow down the job by several times?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

When I run the job in YARN (2.4.0) using the compression (snappy), there is a big impact on the job completion time. For example, I ran the following experiments.
Job: invertedindex
Cluster: 10 slaves VMs(4 CPU 8GB RAM).

Job completion time of 5GB invertedindex without compression(snappy): 226s, with compression: 1600s

Job completion time of 50GB invertedindex without compression(snappy): 2000s, with compression: 14000s

My configuration in mapred-site.xml is like this:

```
<name>mapreduce.map.output.compress</name>  
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.map.output.compress.codec</name>  
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>
```

I have read a lot of material that says that the compression should improve the performance, but here it has slowed down the job by almost 7 times. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the default setting of `mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type` which is set to `RECORD`.

Basically it tries to compress every record, if your records are small text snippets (e.g. a token in your inverted index) it might end up in a larger size than it was before.

You can try to set this property to `BLOCK`, which should compress on a block-level, giving a better compression over redundant text data.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. But I didn't compress the final output, I just compressed the intermediate data. Do you mean set this property to BLOCK as well even though I don't compress the final output? By the way, do I need to install snappy by my self? Is that possible that something is wrong with the hadoop native library?

Comment: I try the BLOCK configuration, it doesn't help.

Comment: Hi Thomas, this problem caused by the native library, thank you.

Comment: @Zeroun it depends on what Snappy implementation you use, there are libraries that don't require native libs and are still comparable in speed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this compression problem by following steps:

1, fix the problem of “Unable to load native-hadoop library”
[Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos)

2, install snappy
http://code.google.com/p/snappy/

3, copy /usr/local/lib/libsnappy* to $HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/

4, configure the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in hadoop-env.sh and in mapred-site.xml

```
<property>  
    <name>mapred.child.env</name>  
    <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native</value>  
</property
```