# Java complains about Hadoop native library

Tags: java, hadoop

On my Ubuntu x32, Java x32, Hadoop 2.5.0 I execute:

```
hduser@master:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /
14/08/19 08:51:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 3 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-08-19 08:37 /data
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-08-19 08:37 /export
drwxrwx---   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-08-19 08:32 /tmp
```

Can someone tell me how to fix the warning?

Java version:

```
hduser@master:~$ java -d64 -version
Error: This Java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM. Please install the desired version.

hduser@master:~$ java -d32 -version
java version "1.7.0_67" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Ubuntu version:

> hduser@master:~$ uname -a Linux master 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu
>   SMP Wed Jun 4 21:02:19 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Hadoop version

> hduser@master:~$ hadoop version Hadoop 2.5.0 Subversion
>   http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1616291 Compiled by
>   jenkins on 2014-08-06T17:31Z Compiled with protoc 2.5.0 From source
>   with checksum 423dcd5a752eddd8e45ead6fd5ff9a24 This command was run
>   using
>   /home/hduser/hadoop-2.5.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.5.0.jar

EDIT:

.bashrc

```
export SQOOP_HOME=/home/hduser/sqoop
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/home/hduser/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/hduser/hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hduser/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PIG_HOME=/home/hduser/pig
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
export HBASE_HOME=/home/hduser/hbase
export HIVE_HOME=/home/hduser/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

Comment: maybe one of the answers to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos will help you

Comment: That link has already been suggested, but it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on your environment pointing to the native library path present in `HADOOP_HOME/lib/native`

**EDIT:**

This configuration may vary depending on your Hadoop distribution or linux flavor.
Here is a [good link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos) with good explanation for CentOS.

Comment: What path have you set? Can you share some details of the same

Comment: I have appended `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native` to my `.bashrc` which you have listed in the question. I have then _sourced_ the file and executed `hdfs dfs -ls /` only to get the same warning. I did not have this problem while using Hadoop 2.4.1 and 2.4.0

Comment: I have seen that post, but I could not find a definitive solution.