# Create directory in hdfs

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

**Command I have used for creating directory in hdfs :**

`hadoop fs -mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/input_dir`

Message I am getting :

```
14/09/19 15:33:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I have checked `~/,bashrc`

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

Comment: you can ignore this warning, above command must have created directory,you want to remove warning or you want to create directory ?

Comment: This is irrelevant to what command you are running. The result should be a new direcoty, as @user3484461 says. See this post for potential help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos

Comment: Just ignore it. This warning is just because you didn't compile Hadoop locally, but download from website. That's totally fine. It will do your work.

Comment: be careful, with that command you are creating a directory in the hadoop filesystem, you aren't forced to follow the same names that exist in local filesystem (you shouldn't imho, tutorials all over the web recommend use `/user/hduser/input`, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Appending the below path in /.bashrc file will remove the warning. However, your command will still execute and create the directory.

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX="$HADOOP_PREFIX -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native"
```