# How do I run native Java that uses Hadoop libs?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have a simple standard Java application that copies file from local file system to remote HDFS.

I was able to run the application successfully using yarn command.
For e.g:

`yarn jar test.jar copyFileApp`

However, above command requires Hadoop to be installed locally, which I don't want. Is there any way I could run the app using native java.
e.g:

`java -cp test.jar copyFileApp`

When I tried with native Java it's complaining that native Hadoop libraries are not found.

e.g.

```
14/09/23 16:36:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Try looking up fatJar and build a jar with the hadoop libraries as part of the jar.  There is a plugin for eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already tried maven-shade-plugin to bundle all libs with the apps but no joy.

Comment: I've never tried maven but fatJar has worked really well for me...

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll have a go at that.

Comment: Why not include other Hadoop libraries in classpath?

Comment: @brso05 the binaries are not shipped with the jar, why should they be? Download a release and put it into your path, like the rest of the world does with libraries as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)