# Error org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hbase, nutch

My Apache Nutch crawler is generating following information in log files.

"WARN  client.ScannerCallable - Ignore, probably already closed
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LeaseException: lease '-3687805264051264867' does not exist"

I have made a change in hbase configuration file(hbase-site.xml).

```
<property>
<name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
<value>100</value>
</property>
```

But it does not effect anything and above same warning is appearing again and again.
Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" error on CentOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure out whats the average size of your record , multiply it with hbase.client.scanner.caching .

if the result > 1 mb you need to increase the scanner.lease.timeout

For complete parameter tuning please visit :

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/hbase/hbase-parameter-tuning/

Comment: hbase.client.scanner.caching represents the number of lines to scan for caching.  When data is large, increase hbase.rpc.timeout and hbase.regionserver.lease.period also recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Some more targeted advice is also given by the hbase documentation and can be found here:

http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/trouble.client.html

quote:

> In some situations clients that fetch data from a RegionServer get a
>   LeaseException instead of the usual Section 12.5.1,
>   “ScannerTimeoutException or UnknownScannerException”. Usually the
>   source of the exception is
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.Leases.removeLease(Leases.java:230)
>   (line number may vary). It tends to happen in the context of a
>   slow/freezing RegionServer#next call. It can be prevented by having
>   hbase.rpc.timeout > hbase.regionserver.lease.period. Harsh J
>   investigated the issue as part of the mailing list thread HBase

i.e, try setting **hbase.rpc.timeout** to a value higher than **hbase.regionserver.lease.period**