# hadoop2.6.0 sudo sbin/start-dfs.sh

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

when I try to start hadoop in a  pseudo-distributed mode.I was caught in this problem. I'm just a beginner of hadoop. Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

```
lty@lty-Ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0$ sudo sbin/start-dfs.sh

Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
```

It's highly recommended that you fix the library with `execstack -c <libfile>`, or link it with `-z noexecstack`.

```
15/01/20 19:43:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Starting namenodes on [localhost]
root@localhost's password:
```

Answer (score 0):

First one is a warning, you can ignore it, for more understanding on problem please read [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos)

To eliminate password prompt for each operation you should set up passwordless ssh for the user you want to start Hadoop with.
Please follow the steps mentioned here - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Comment: I'v set up the  passwordless ssh,and closed  the firewall. but it still can not work. it can just run  in a non-distributed mode. today I installed  the hadoop 1.2.1 version but I still meet the same problem. lty@lty-Ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1$ sudo bin/start-all.sh
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-lty-Ubuntu.out
root@localhost's password: 
root@localhost's password: localhost: Permission denied, please try again.
I really don't know why. but this time the warning has gone.

Comment: Something is wrong here, if you have setup passwordless ssh for root user it shouldn't ask you for entering password when you start the namenode, can you update your question with the namenode log? Also that warning is specific to 2.x.

Comment: thanks for your help.I've solved this problem by changing the configeration in host file. problem was caused by the configeration.