# Why I can't access http://hadoop-master:50070 when i define dfs.namenode.http-address

Tags: hadoop

The Hadoop Version is 2.7.1
Modify the hdfs.xml , add two properties：

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>HADOOP-MASTER:50070</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
    <value>HADOOP-SLAVE-1:50090</value>
</property>
```

And restart the hadoop cluster,but I can't access http://hadoop-master:50070.
the namenode process is alive.
and

```
 [hadoop@HADOOP-MASTER ~]$ lsof -i:50070
 COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
 java    26541 hadoop  184u  IPv4 1261606      0t0  TCP HADOOP-MASTER:50070 (LISTEN)
```

But when I remove the `dfs.namenode.http-address` property,the 50070 worked on.

So,The Problem is what  `dfs.namenode.http-address` property mean,I guess it define the node who can access?

Comment: Have you tried accessing by name of the property and not by value?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu hmm,access name of the property?,you mean `dfs.namenode.http-address`?,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That value is defined as "The *address* and the base port where the dfs namenode web ui will listen on" and defaults to 0.0.0.0:50070, which means it is publicly accessible to all machines that can reach it.

Notice that is says address, not hostname. If you need to change this value from the default, use an IP address, not a physical machine name.

Source: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Comment: thank you for answer,so,the property `fs.default.name` in  configure file `core-site.xml `also defined as the address where others listen on ?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Other what? That setting is not an address. It is defined as "The name of the default file system. A URI whose scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation." It's default value is `file:///`,  which is the URI for the local filesystem.