# How to Fix Warnings in Hadoop Installation

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bigdata

I'm trying to install Hadoop onto an xUbuntu PC.  Ubuntu 14.10 (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64). Installed Hadoop 2.6

When I go to run

```
    n@Dell:~$ start-dfs.sh
15/03/28 12:27:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
n@localhost's password: 
localhost: Connection closed by UNKNOWN
na@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-n-datanode-Dell.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
n@0.0.0.0's password: 
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-n-secondarynamenode-Dell.out
15/03/28 12:30:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I'm pretty sure it should still run fine, but I really don't like having errors like this. I've googled this a lot and haven't found a solution that actually works.

I'm not using CentOS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" error on CentOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos)

Comment: I'm not using CentOS

Comment: Do you believe that centos would behave differently than GNU/linux?  My intuition/gut is they would be the same - but feel free to comment.