# Hadoop “Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform” error on docker-spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, docker

I am using [docker-spark](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark). After starting `spark-shell`, it outputs:

```
15/05/21 04:28:22 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader: Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:no hadoop in java.library.path
15/05/21 04:28:22 DEBUG NativeCodeLoader: java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

The environment variables of this `spark container` are:

```
bash-4.1# export
declare -x BOOTSTRAP="/etc/bootstrap.sh"
declare -x HADOOP_COMMON_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop"
declare -x HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop"
declare -x HADOOP_HDFS_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop"
declare -x HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop"
declare -x HADOOP_PREFIX="/usr/local/hadoop"
declare -x HADOOP_YARN_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop"
declare -x HOME="/"
declare -x HOSTNAME="sandbox"
declare -x JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/default"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/java/default/bin:/usr/local/spark/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin"
declare -x PWD="/"
declare -x SHLVL="3"
declare -x SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark"
declare -x SPARK_JAR="hdfs:///spark/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
declare -x YARN_CONF_DIR="/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop"
```

After referring [Hadoop “Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform” error on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos), I have done the following:

(1) Check the `hadoop` library:

```
bash-4.1# file /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.1.0
/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

Yes, it is `64-bit` library.

(2) Try adding the `HADOOP_OPTS` environment variable:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native"
```

It doesn't work, and reports the same error.

(3) Try adding the `HADOOP_OPTS` and `HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR` environment variable:

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

It still doesn't work, and reports the same error.

Could anyone give some clues about the issue?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Adding the `Hadoop` library into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` fix this problem:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem. I wonder how this got to happen, since I wasn't getting the error after a clean Spark installation...

Comment: Strange, it's not mentioned in the Spark doc (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html) but it works! Thanks.

Comment: I had to add `log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader=DEBUG` to my `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/log4j.properties`.
After that I could see the following error: `Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path`.
This is the working solution for that error, just add the line to your user's `.profile/.bashrc`. Thank you!

Comment: I had to use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Because the step (3) path is an error. It should be:

```bash
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR"
```

Then it works.

---

Debug this issue is very easy, edit the log4j profile `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/log4j.properties` Add a new line

```bash
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader=DEBUG
```

Then exec the command

```bash
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

The log shows the path is an error.

```
2022-10-10 16:32:30,599 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
2022-10-10 16:32:30,601 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: Failed to load native-hadoop with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path
2022-10-10 16:32:30,601 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: java.library.path=/opt/hadoop/lib
```