# Hadoop native libraries not found on OS/X

Tags: macos, hadoop, hadoop-native-library

I have downloaded `hadoop` source code from github and compiled with the `native` option:

```
mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

I then  copied the  `.dylib` files to the $HADOOP_HOME/lib

```
cp -p hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/hadoop-common-2.7.1/lib/native/*.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/share/hadoop/lib
```

The LD_LIBRARY_PATH was updated and hdfs restarted:

```
 echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/lib:
 /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home//jre/lib
```

(Note: this also means that the answer to [Hadoop “Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform” error on docker-spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369380/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-docker) does not work for me..)

But `checknative` still returns uniformly `false`:

```
$stop-dfs.sh && start-dfs.sh && hadoop checknative
16/06/13 16:12:32 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Stopping namenodes on [sparkbook]
sparkbook: stopping namenode
localhost: stopping datanode
Stopping secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: stopping secondarynamenode
16/06/13 16:12:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/06/13 16:12:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [sparkbook]
sparkbook: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/logs/hadoop-macuser-namenode-sparkbook.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/logs/hadoop-macuser-datanode-sparkbook.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/logs/hadoop-macuser-secondarynamenode-sparkbook.out
16/06/13 16:13:05 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/06/13 16:13:05 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Native library checking:
hadoop:  false
zlib:    false
snappy:  false
lz4:     false
bzip2:   false
openssl: false
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To get this working on a fresh install of macOS 10.12, I had to do the following:

1. Install build dependencies using [homebrew](http://brew.sh):

   ```
   brew install cmake maven openssl protobuf@2.5 snappy
   ```
2. Check out hadoop source code

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git
   cd hadoop
   git checkout rel/release-2.7.3
   ```
3. Apply the below patch to the build:

   ```
   diff --git a/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/CMakeLists.txt b/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/CMakeLists.txt
   index 942b19c..8b34881 100644
   --- a/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/CMakeLists.txt
   +++ b/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/CMakeLists.txt
   @@ -16,6 +16,8 @@
    # limitations under the License.
    #

   +SET(CUSTOM_OPENSSL_PREFIX /usr/local/opt/openssl)
   +
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

    # Default to release builds
   @@ -116,8 +118,8 @@ set(T main/native/src/test/org/apache/hadoop)
    GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(HADOOP_ZLIB_LIBRARY ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} NAME)

    SET(STORED_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
   -set_find_shared_library_version("1")
   -find_package(BZip2 QUIET)
   +set_find_shared_library_version("1.0")
   +find_package(BZip2 REQUIRED)
    if (BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR AND BZIP2_LIBRARIES)
        GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(HADOOP_BZIP2_LIBRARY ${BZIP2_LIBRARIES} NAME)
        set(BZIP2_SOURCE_FILES
   diff --git a/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/core-site.xml b/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/core-site.xml
   index d2ddf89..ac8e351 100644
   --- a/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/core-site.xml
   +++ b/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/core-site.xml
   @@ -17,4 +17,8 @@
    <!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

    <configuration>
   +<property>
   +<name>io.compression.codec.bzip2.library</name>
   +<value>libbz2.dylib</value>
   +</property>
    </configuration>
   diff --git a/hadoop-tools/hadoop-pipes/pom.xml b/hadoop-tools/hadoop-pipes/pom.xml
   index 34c0110..70f23a4 100644
   --- a/hadoop-tools/hadoop-pipes/pom.xml
   +++ b/hadoop-tools/hadoop-pipes/pom.xml
   @@ -52,7 +52,7 @@
                        <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/native"/>
                        <exec executable="cmake" dir="${project.build.directory}/native" 
                            failonerror="true">
   -                      <arg line="${basedir}/src/ -DJVM_ARCH_DATA_MODEL=${sun.arch.data.model}"/>
   +                      <arg line="${basedir}/src/ -DJVM_ARCH_DATA_MODEL=${sun.arch.data.model} -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl"/>
                        </exec>
                        <exec executable="make" dir="${project.build.directory}/native" failonerror="true">
                          <arg line="VERBOSE=1"/>
   ```
4. Build hadoop from source:

   ```
   mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
   ```
5. Specify `JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH` when running hadoop:

   ```
   $ JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop checknative -a
   16/10/14 20:16:32 INFO bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-bzip2 library libbz2.dylib
   16/10/14 20:16:32 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
   Native library checking:
   hadoop:  true /Users/admin/Desktop/hadoop/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-2.7.3/lib/native/libhadoop.dylib
   zlib:    true /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
   snappy:  true /usr/local/lib/libsnappy.1.dylib
   lz4:     true revision:99
   bzip2:   true /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
   openssl: true /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib
   ```

Comment: How/where did you find the details indicating the above patch were required ? Please update the answer with that as well as the url (or info how to navigate to the url) for  the patch.

Comment: @javadba The patch comes from many hours of reading the code, adding debugging output statements, recompiling and trying again ...

Comment: So it's ***your*** patch .. well that makes me feel better for having *punted* at the time this came up.

Comment: Also after installing protobuf do not forget to register it in PATH, otherwise maven build fails with protoc --version error
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/protobuf@2.5/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: I get the following error with the above brew install protobuf@2.5: protobuf@2.5 was deleted from homebrew/core in commit 60f11879:
  protobuf@2.*: remove (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/38446)

Comment: to get protobuf follow https://codetips.coloza.com/2015/07/compile-hadoop-from-source.html

Answer (score 6):

There are some missing steps in @andrewdotn's response above:

1)  For step (3), create the patch by adding the text posted to a text file e.g. "patch.txt", and then execute "git apply patch.txt"

2) In addition to copying the files as directed by javadba, certain applications also require that you set:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH:${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
```

Answer (score 1):

The needed step is to copy the `*.dylib` from the `git` sources build dir into the `$HADOOP_HOME/<common dir>lib` dir for your platform . For `OS/X` installed via `brew` it is:

```
cp /git/hadoop/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native/ /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/share/hadoop/common/
```

We can see the required libs there now:

```
$ll /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/share/hadoop/common/*.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 macuser  staff  149100 Jun 13 13:44 /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/share/hadoop/common/libhadoop.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 macuser  staff  149100 Jun 13 13:44 /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/share/hadoop/common/libhadoop.1.0.0.dylib
```

And now the `hadoop checknative` command works:

```
$hadoop checknative

6/06/15 09:10:59 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop:  true /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/share/hadoop/common/libhadoop.dylib
zlib:    true /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
snappy:  false
lz4:     true revision:99
bzip2:   false
openssl: false build does not support openssl.
```

Answer (score 1):

As an update to @andrewdotn answer, here is the `patch.txt` file to be used with Hadoop 2.8.1:

```
diff --git a/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/CMakeLists.txt b/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/CMakeLists.txt
index c93bfe78546..e8918f9ca29 100644
--- a/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -20,6 +20,8 @@
 # CMake configuration.
 #

+SET(CUSTOM_OPENSSL_PREFIX /usr/local/opt/openssl)
+
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

 list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
@@ -50,8 +52,8 @@ get_filename_component(HADOOP_ZLIB_LIBRARY ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} NAME)

 # Look for bzip2.
 set(STORED_CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
-hadoop_set_find_shared_library_version("1")
-find_package(BZip2 QUIET)
+hadoop_set_find_shared_library_version("1.0")
+find_package(BZip2 REQUIRED)
 if(BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR AND BZIP2_LIBRARIES)
     get_filename_component(HADOOP_BZIP2_LIBRARY ${BZIP2_LIBRARIES} NAME)
     set(BZIP2_SOURCE_FILES
diff --git a/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/core-site.xml b/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/core-site.xml
index d2ddf893e49..ac8e351f1c8 100644
--- a/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/core-site.xml
+++ b/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/core-site.xml
@@ -17,4 +17,8 @@
 <!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

 <configuration>
+<property>
+<name>io.compression.codec.bzip2.library</name>
+<value>libbz2.dylib</value>
+</property>
 </configuration>
diff --git a/hadoop-tools/hadoop-pipes/pom.xml b/hadoop-tools/hadoop-pipes/pom.xml
index 8aafad0f7eb..d4832542265 100644
--- a/hadoop-tools/hadoop-pipes/pom.xml
+++ b/hadoop-tools/hadoop-pipes/pom.xml
@@ -55,7 +55,7 @@
                     <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/native"/>
                     <exec executable="cmake" dir="${project.build.directory}/native" 
                         failonerror="true">
-                      <arg line="${basedir}/src/ -DJVM_ARCH_DATA_MODEL=${sun.arch.data.model}"/>
+                      <arg line="${basedir}/src/ -DJVM_ARCH_DATA_MODEL=${sun.arch.data.model} -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl"/>
                     </exec>
                     <exec executable="make" dir="${project.build.directory}/native" failonerror="true">
                       <arg line="VERBOSE=1"/>
```

Comment: It has a problem compiling with latest openssl. I had to build openssl-1.01u in order for it to work. Also had to change /usr/local/opt/openssl to point to openssl-1.0.1u directory.