# never ending job in mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, mapreduce

I have set some MapReduce configuration in my `main` method as so

```
configuration.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.address", "localhost:54311");
configuration.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
configuration.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "localhost:8032");
```

Now when I launch the `mapreduce` task, the process is tracked (I can see it in my cluster dashboard (the one listening on port 8088)), but the process never finishes. It remains blocked at the following line:

```
15/06/30 15:56:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/06/30 15:56:17 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
15/06/30 15:56:18 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/06/30 15:56:18 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/06/30 15:56:18 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/06/30 15:56:18 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1435241671439_0008
15/06/30 15:56:19 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1435241671439_0008
15/06/30 15:56:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://10.0.0.10:8088/proxy/application_1435241671439_0008/
15/06/30 15:56:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1435241671439_0008
```

Someone has an idea?

Edit : in my `yarn nodemanager` log, I have this message

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Event EventType: KILL_CONTAINER sent to absent container container_1435241671439_0003_03_000001
2015-06-30 15:44:38,396 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Event EventType: KILL_CONTAINER sent to absent container container_1435241671439_0002_04_000001
```

Edit 2 :

I also have in the `yarn manager` log, some exception that happened sooner (for a precedent mapreduce call) :

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [0.0.0.0:8040] java.net.BindException: Address already in use; For more details see:
```

Solution : I killed all the daemon processes and restarted again `hadoop` ! In fact, when I ran `jps`, I was still getting `hadoop daemons` though I had stopped them. This was a  mismatch of `HADOOP_PID_DIR`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos)?

Comment: @Mena my problem is not the warning since it has always shown up with no peculiar consequence

Comment: Wasn't too hopeful either. Maybe something in the logic of the job itself?

Comment: @Mena I 've jsut tried this with some WordCount example and I have the same problem !

Comment: @Mena I have just updated my post

Comment: Just noticed [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3339)... which version are you using?

Comment: @Mena I am using 2.7.0

Comment: Then I'm afraid this goes beyond my limited knowledge :(

Comment: @Mena I have added a second edit. Hope it helps

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully someone with a little more hands-on will pick this up.

Comment: @Nema I found the solution !

Comment: Nice. I suggest you add an answer and accept your own.

Comment: @Mena that's what I done !

Answer (score 0):

The default port of nodemanage of yarn is 8040. The error says that the port is already in use. Stop all the hadoop process, if you dont have data, may be format namenode once and try running the job again. From both of your edits, the issue is surely with node manager

Comment: thank you but in fact I realize that I run the scripts to stop all daemons. But when I run `jps`, there are still appearing. How can I stop them ?

Comment: You can use, bin/stop-all.sh (or stop-dfs.sh and stop-yarn.sh). Also format the name node if still problem persists(careful as you will loose data). Some help [here](http://www.cs.brandeis.edu//~cs147a/lab/hadoop-troubleshooting/)

Answer (score 0):

Solution : I killed all the daemon processes and restarted again hadoop ! In fact, when I ran `jps`, I was still getting hadoop daemons though I had stopped them. This was related to a mismatch of `HADOOP_PID_DIR`