# hadoop WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform

Tags: hadoop

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php).
`start-all.sh` output:

```
hduser@ubuntu12:~/hadoop/sbin$ start-dfs.sh
15/07/27 15:24:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/07/27 15:24:12 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
15/07/27 15:24:12 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
15/07/27 15:24:12 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
15/07/27 15:24:12 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
15/07/27 15:24:12 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
15/07/27 15:24:12 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-ubuntu12.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-ubuntu12.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-ubuntu12.out
15/07/27 15:24:29 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/07/27 15:24:30 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
15/07/27 15:24:30 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
15/07/27 15:24:30 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
15/07/27 15:24:30 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
15/07/27 15:24:30 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
15/07/27 15:24:30 WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>
```

Hadoop is running well, I have run `curl http://localhost:50070/` proving that.

I know `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader Unable to load native-hadoop library`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos).
But I can not figure out what cause `WARN conf.Configuration: bad conf file: element not <property>`.

Comment: Can you share the configurations.

Comment: @AmalGJose  my configurations is same as the tutorial, please check that

Comment: Some problem with the file: config. Can you try removing the file: prefix from directories