# Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder and Unable to load native-hadoop library

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm new with Hadoop and during one MapReduce task I got the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
15/09/18 07:31:10 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here's what your errors mean:

For `SLF4J`:

```
SLF4J: **Failed to load class** "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

As you can tell, you do not have the appropriate class (***Failed to load class***) for `SLF4J` to work so it defaults to no logging (*(NOP) logger implementation*). Following the suggested [**link**](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) you can see that the solution for this is:

> Placing one **(and only one)** of `slf4j-nop.jar`, `slf4j-simple.jar`, `slf4j-log4j12.jar`, `slf4j-jdk14.jar` or `logback-classic.jar` on the class path should solve the problem

For Hadoop:

```
15/09/18 07:31:10 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

This just means that the native library cannot be found, it generally doesn't affect the way Hadoop functions. As for the native library:

> The native library just contains implementations of certain components for performance reasons and for non-availability of Java implementations. These components are available in a single, dynamically-linked native library called the native hadoop library. On the *nix platforms the library is named libhadoop.so.

Anyway, if you *really* want to get rid of the warning, you can follow one of the many solutions offered [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos).