# Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform

Tags: hadoop

Whenever I try running the .jar file on Hadoop, it shows an error:

> "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using
>   builtin-java classes where applicable"

What could be the reason? I'm not able to figure out.

```
hdfs dfs -cat /outer22/*
```

`outer22` is my output file.

Comment: Could you post the complete output from the command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop include **native libraries** in the binary distribution for *nix platforms for high performance and the Java version of those libraries for the others.

If your installation is for development, then you could ignore the message. In production could be better use native libraries.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html