# Which version of Spark to download?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I understand you can download Spark source code (1.5.1), or prebuilt binaries for various versions of Hadoop. As of Oct 2015, the Spark webpage http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html  has prebuilt binaries against Hadoop 2.6+, 2.4+, 2.3, and 1.X.

I'm not sure what version to download.

I want to run a Spark cluster in standalone mode using AWS machines.

`<EDIT>`

I will be running a 24/7 streaming process. My data will be coming from a Kafka stream. I thought about using spark-ec2, but since I already have persistent ec2 machines, I thought I might as well use them.

My understanding is that since my persistent workers need to perform `checkpoint()`, it needs to have access to some kind of shared file system with the master node. S3 seems like a logical choice.
`</EDIT>`

This means I need to access S3, but not hdfs. I do not have Hadoop installed.

I got a pre-built Spark for Hadoop 2.6. I can run it in local mode, such as the wordcount example. However, whenever I start it up, I get this message

```
WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Is this a problem? Do I need hadoop?

`<EDIT>`

It's not a show stopper but I want to make sure I understand the reason of this warning message. I was under the assumption that Spark doesn't need Hadoop, so why is it even showing up?
`</EDIT>`

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure what version to download.

This consideration will also be guided by what existing code you are using, features you require, and bug tolerance.

> I want to run a Spark cluster in standalone mode using AWS instances.

Have you considered simply running [Apache Spark on Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-apache-spark-on-amazon-emr/)? See also [How can I run Spark on a cluster?](http://spark.apache.org/faq.html) from Spark's FAQ, and their reference to their [EC2 scripts](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html).

> This means I need to access S3, but not hdfs

One does not imply the other. You can run a Spark cluster on EC2 instances perfectly fine, and never have to access S3. While many examples are written using S3 access through the out-of-the-box [S3 "fs" drivers for the Hadoop library](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3), pay attention that there are now 3 different access methods. Configure as appropriate.

However, your choice of libraries to load will depend on where your data is. Spark can access any filesystem supported by Hadoop, [from which there are several to choose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#Other_file_systems).

Is your data even in files? Depending on your application, and where your data is, you may only need to use Data Frame over [SQL](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases), [Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md), or others!

> However, whenever I start it up, I get this message
>
> > WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
> >     Is this a problem? Do I need hadoop?

Not a problem. It is telling you that it is falling back to a non-optimum implementation. Others have [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning), too.

In general, it sounds like you don't have any application needs right now, so you don't have any dependencies. Dependencies are what would drive different configurations such as access to S3, HDFS, etc.

> I can run it in local mode, such as the wordcount example.

So, you're good?

**UPDATE**

> > I've edited the original post
>
> My data will be coming from a Kafka stream. ... My understanding is that .. my persistent workers need to perform `checkpoint()`.

Yes, the [Direct Kafka](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/30/improvements-to-kafka-integration-of-spark-streaming.html) approach is available from Spark 1.3 on, and per that article, uses checkpoints. These require a ["fault-tolerant, reliable file system (e.g., HDFS, S3, etc.)"](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing). See the [Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html) for your version for specific caveats.

> So why [do I see the Hadoop warning message]?

The Spark download only comes with so many Hadoop client libraries. With a fully-configured Hadoop installation, there are also platform-specific native binaries for certain packages. These get used if available. To use them, [augment Spark's classpath](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html); otherwise, the loader will fallback to less performant versions.

Depending on your configuration, you may be able to take advantage of a fully configured Hadoop or HDFS installation. You mention taking advantage of your existing, persistent EC2 instances, rather than using something new. There's a tradeoff between S3 and HDFS: S3 is a new resource (more cost) but survives when your instance is offline (can take compute down and have persisted storage); however, S3 might suffer from latency compared to HDFS (you already have the machines, why not run a filesystem over them?), as well as not [behave like a filesystem](http://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219) in all cases. This tradeoff is described by Microsoft for [choosing Azure storage vs. HDFS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/#_benefits), for example, when using HDInsight.

Comment: thanks for the comment. i've edited the original post. really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

We're also running Spark on EC2 against S3 (via the `s3n` file system). We had some issue with the pre-built versions for Hadoop 2.x. Regrettably I don't remember what the issue was. But in the end we're running with the pre-built Spark for Hadoop 1.x and it works great.

Comment: Sorry about the anecdotal answer. Hope it's helpful anyway.