# Copy File From local to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I know there is a samiliar title question but whta we ask is different.
I Tried this

```
hduser@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/Text /home/hduser/Text
```

And I get this:

```
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

15/10/14 10:15:21 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
copyFromLocal: `/home/hduser/Text': No such file or directory
​
```

However, I do have the /home/hduser/Text And I'm using hdfs command 
What does the error mean? How can i fix it

Comment: Have you tried to specify server and port in the destination path: `hdfs://<server>:<port>/home/hduser/Text` ?

Comment: I'm woring on single node. Do I need to specify server and port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I do have the /home/hduser/Text And I'm using hdfs command
>   What does the error mean? How can i fix it

Either /home/hduser/Text doesn't exist or Syntax is incorrect. For later case, try below:

**`hduser@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal  /home/hduser/Text /tmp/Text`**

> ```
>  To get rid of warning - DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated. Instead use the hdfs command for it.
> ```

**`hduser@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Text /tmp/Text`**

```
copyFromLocal:

Usage: hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal <localsrc> URI

Similar to put command, except that the source is restricted to a local file reference.

Options:

    The -f option will overwrite the destination if it already exists.
```

Comment: But the /tmp/Text is my local file

Comment: By using hdfs dfs command, the warning about hdfs command disappeared. However I still have 15/10/14 11:30:56 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Comment: Please check if /home/hduser/Text exist on HDFS. run  hadoop fs -ls /home/hduser/Text

Comment: How can I Check the files on HDFS? can you show me the exact command?

Comment: hadoop fs -ls /home/hduser/Text

Comment: hduser@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser
15/10/14 11:37:05 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: `/user/hduser': No such file or directory

Comment: it says - No such file or directory and hence error

Comment: It just a warning. see this SO link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92295/discussion-between-gavin-niu-and-vinkal).

Comment: @GavinNiu - My pleasure.