# Hadoop - Native library missing

Tags: java, hadoop

**I am trying to access remote file system from my windows machine**

My code is very simple:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://remoteHostName.com:8020/");
    FileSystem fs = FieSystem.get(conf);
    System.out.println("Hi");
```

**Warn:**

```
    unable to load native hadoop library for your platform using builtin
     java classes where applicable
```

I am not able to understand the reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning ?

Comment: Yes. But why should I set java library path in windows. It is accessing remote hdfs.