# Spark with HDFS without YARN

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am trying to configure HDFS for spark. Simple running `spark-sub
mit with --master spark://IP:7077 --deploy-mode cluster....` ends up with

```
16/04/08 10:16:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Then it end work.
I downloaded and lanuched Hadoop cluster, for testing purposes only one machine. I also set envirtoment variables, althouth I think that I forget about some of them. In the fact I set:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/spark/bin  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/
```

Could you try to help me ?
I followed it: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/cbw/spark.html

Comment: what's the question here ?

Comment: I don't know why I get this error. If I set all needed enviroment varibals ?

Comment: please update with the error message !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)

Comment: No, it doesnt help

Comment: Can you update your question with actual error message ???

Comment: Then first it's a duplicate, a secondly it's just a warning. Your project wont fail from it.

Comment: Well I'm getting this error all the time, and it doesn't stop application from working.