# Hadoop: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform

Tags: java, hadoop

I've installed Hadoop 2.7.2 single node on Ubuntu and I want to run the java wordcount program. The compilation and the creation of the jar file are done succesfully, but when I run the jar file on Hadoop I receive this message:

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I set environment variables by editing .bashrc file:

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib
```

When I type hadoop checknative -a I get this:

```
hadoop: true /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib: true /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
snappy: false 
lz4: true revision:99
bzip2: false
openssl: true /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so

16/05/09 00:48:53 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Hadoop version: 2.7.2

Ubuntu version: 14.04

Could anyone give some clues about the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)

Answer (score 4):

Move your compiled native library files to $HADOOP_HOME/lib folder.

Then set your environment variables by editing .bashrc file

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib  
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
```

Make sure your compiled native library files are in $HADOOP_HOME/lib folder.

It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add the commands lines below to `hadoop-env.sh`, it should suppress the errors encountered

```
export HADOOP_HOME_WARN_SUPPRESS=1
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER="WARN,DRFA"
```

Comment: I configured hadoop on raspberry where none of the library files are native and while it all works it's nice to suppress the warnings. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the hadoop jars-"hadoop-common.jar and hadoop-core.jar" to your class path. You can simply do it in eclipse ans while creating a jar file those jars will be referenced automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error.

I solved it by updating the winutils.exe and hadoop.dll files to the later version.
:)

https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-3.3.1
(where I was able to find different versions)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

edit the file `hadoop-env.sh` in `/usr/local/etc/hadoop`

Adding Hadoop library into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

try it, works for me