# Folder Not Created with hadoop fs -mkdir

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

Hey I am installing HIVE in a Hadoop 2.0 Multi Node cluster ,and I am not able to Create  folder using this command :

**[hadoop@master ~]$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp**

`16/07/19 14:20:15 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

**[hadoop@master ~]$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse** 
`16/07/19 14:24:12 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

**Importantly I am not able to find the Created Folder ? Where it will go and create I am not sure. Please help.**

JPS for Hadoop is working fine:
**[hadoop@master ~]$ jps**

```
2977 ResourceManager  
2613 DataNode  
3093 NodeManager  
2822 SecondaryNameNode  
2502 NameNode  
5642 Jps
```

Comment: So `$ hadoop fs -ls /` doesn't show `/tmp` on HDFS?

Comment: Yes now it shows up the below but "Super Group" ?  'drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-07-19 13:37 /apple  
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-07-19 13:42 /steve_jobs  
drwxrwxr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-07-18 12:51 /tmp  
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-07-19 13:22 /user  
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2016-07-19 15:50 /usr'

Comment: Ok, so its been created. Its owned by `hadoop` and is in the `supergroup` group. What's your question?

Comment: Why am I not able to see this Physically ? and I want to Change the UserGroup To hadoop

Comment: What do you mean physically? You access HDFS via the hadoop CLI. You can change the group using something like - `$ hadoop fs -chown hadoop:hadoop /tmp`

Answer (score 1):

The warning you are getting after running `-mkdir` command does not impact the Hadoop functionality. It's just a warning, just ignore it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning) for details.

About creating directories under root i.e. "/", it is just one-time activity and should be done by superuser. Once you create the root directories like "/tmp", "/user" etc., then you can create user specific foders like "/user/hduser" and own them using commands:

`sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp`

OR

`sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse`

Once you have the main folder ready, just own it with the user who will be using it:

`sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chown hduser:hadoop /user/hive/warehouse`

If you want to find the files/directories created on HDFS, then you have to interact with HDFS filesystem using CLI commands only

e.g. `hdfs dfs -ls /`

The data which is created on HDFS has a physical location on your local filesystem also, but you'll not see that location as files and directories. Look for the `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` properties in 'hdfs-site.xml' under your installation, usually located at: "/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"