# Correct configuration for Maven to load Native Hadoop Libraries

Tags: linux, hadoop, cloudera, mahout, hadoop2

I am trying to run a Mahout project which I wrote in Eclipse with the Mahout and Hadoop libraries. It loads in a dataset and runs the [FPGrowth](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout/mahout-core/org/apache/mahout/fpm/pfpgrowth/fpgrowth/FPGrowth.html#generateTopKFrequentPatterns(java.util.Iterator,%20java.util.Collection,%20long,%20int,%20java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector,%20org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.convertors.StatusUpdater)) algorithm. I set up the following Run configuration to run the project:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.patternmatching.RecommendApp.TopPatternMatches
```

After running the program, I get the following error message:

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I researched this issue, and realized that the Native hadoop libraries have to either be compiled, or downloaded from Apache ([Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)) . I downloaded the libraries on a Cloudera Quickstart VM, on which I set up Mahout and Maven, along with my project package. After running it in cloudera, I get the same error. I also ran the `Hadoop checknative -a` command, which verifies that the Native libraries are available:

```
[root@quickstart /]# hadoop checknative -a
16/10/22 19:32:16 INFO bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-bzip2 library system-native
16/10/22 19:32:16 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop:  true /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib:    true /lib64/libz.so.1
snappy:  true /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/libsnappy.so.1
lz4:     true revision:99
bzip2:   true /lib64/libbz2.so.1
openssl: true /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so
```

The output of the command verifies that the libraries are available, but are not being correctly loaded into the program or classpath. I am not sure how to configure Maven so that it loads in the Hadoop native libraries when running the program. This is the dependencies section of the Maven `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-alpha1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
        <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and the command I run to execute my Mahout java program is

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.patternmatching.RecommendApp.TopPatternMatches
```

How can I configure Maven to see these libraries so they are used in the program?