# Problems of running spark for Python

Tags: python, pyspark

two questions:

1. how to run python3 in spark module? I run `/bin/.pyspark` and it automatically runs Python 2.7. How to run Python3?
2. After I run pyspark, it pops a warning like this: 16/12/29 17:33:37 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
   Does it mean I downloaded the wrong spark platform?

I am using MacProBook. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps for:

**1 time:**

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 ./bin/pyspark
```

**Everytime:**

```
>>>cd
>>>vim .bashrc
```

Add these 2 lines at the end of file and save the file.

`export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3`
`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3`

After exiting from the file, source the `.bashrc` file to reflect changes.

```
>>>source .bashrc
```

Now when you start spark, it will use Python3.

---

Read this for your 2nd error. It has got to do with 32bit vs 64bit source code compilation:

[Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)

Answer (score 0):

add this in your ~/.bashrc
`

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/"

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR="/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/"
```

or :
`export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native"`