# Hadoop on Windows - WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Tags: windows, hadoop

While running `hadoop` on Windows 7 64-bit, I got stuck on this:

> `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`
>   `WARN common.Util: Path /hadoop-2.6.5/data/namenode should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.`
>   `WARN common.Util: Path /hadoop-2.6.5/data/namenode should be specified as a URI in configuration files`

How can I solve these warnings?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)

Comment: I believe OP is running this on Windows 7. The links above all point to solutions in CentOS, Ubuntu, etc.

Comment: I agree with Bookamp. All above links are non-windows specific. I am also facing same issue. I am not trying to building from hadoop source. I downloaded hadoop binaries (2.8.1 tar gz) and trying to run on windows 7 (64 bit) using cygwin but facing same error. Seems IO Native library is an issue here. Can I really not run from binaries ? I don't want to build from source as that has so many other SDKs dependencies.

Answer (score 11):

There are no native hadoop libraries for Windows (see [Native Libraries Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html) so the warning is expected and it's just a warning, not an error. The same applies for Mac OS X environments, no native libraries provided either.

If you want to suppress the `WARN` just edit the `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/log4j.properties` (usually something like `etc/hadoop/log4j.properties`) and add the following:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader=ERROR
```

Only errors (and not warnings) will be logged from now on.

Comment: Have you read this <i>Hadoop on Linux includes optional Native IO support. However Native IO is mandatory on Windows and without it you will not be able to get your installation working. You must follow all the instructions from BUILDING.txt to ensure that Native IO support is built correctly.</i> from here https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows

Answer (score 0):

This code below can be reassuring that the environment variable is configured properly. As Ruben states below, good information on how to set log4j to ignore the warning, is to reconfigure your log4j file to only list out the package information when it is in error.  Thanks for that Ruben.

```
import os
for name, value in os.environ.items():
    print("{0}: {1}".format(name, value))
```

Comment: You can just run `set` in CMD. You dont need Python for this