# pyspark on Anaconda: ] was unexpected at this time

Tags: pyspark, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I am following [this page](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/install-pyspark-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook) to install PySpark in Anaconda on Windows 10.  In step #6 for validating PySpark, Python [could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73823644).  I found that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76552980/2153235) initially helped me progress to the point of seeing the PySpark banner.  Here is my adaption of the solution in the form of commands issued at the Anaconda prompt (not the Anaconda Powershell prompt):

```
set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python
set PYSPARK_PYTHON=python
# set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\pkgs\pyspark-3.4.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0\site-packages
set PYTHONPATH=c:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\pkgs\pyspark-3.2.1-py39haa95532_0\Lib\site-packages
pyspark
```

As shown above, the PYTHONPATH had to be modified to match the folder tree in my own installation.  Essentially, I searched for a folder in `c:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\pkgs\pyspark-3.2.1-py39haa95532_0` named `site-packages`.  I assume that the PySpark version was selected by Conda during installation to satisify package dependencies in the current `py39` environment, which contains Python 3.9.  I use this version for compatibility with others.

PySpark ran for the *1st time* after this, but with many, many errors (see Annex below).  As I am new to Python, Anaconda, and PySpark, I find the errors to be confusing to say the least.  As shown in the Annex, however, I did get the Spark banner and the Python prompt.

As my very first step to troubleshooting the errors, I tried closing and reopening the Conda prompt window.  However, the error from this *2nd run* of `pyspark` was *different* -- and equally confusing.

**pyspark output from *2nd* run:**

```
set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python
set PYSPARK_PYTHON=python
set PYTHONPATH=c:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\pkgs\pyspark-3.2.1-py39haa95532_0\Lib\site-packages
pyspark

   ] was unexpected at this time.
```

To trace the cause of this different error message, I searched for the file that is executed when I issue `pyspark`.  Here are the candidate files:

```
where pyspark

   C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\pyspark
   C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\pyspark.cmd
```

I noted that the 1st script `pyspark` is a *Bash* script, so it's not suprising that "] was unexpected at this time."  I assumed that the 2nd script `pyspark.cmd` is for invocation from Windows's CMD interpreter, of which the Conda prompt is a customization, e.g., by setting certain environment variables.  Therefore, I ran `pyspark.cmd`, but it generated the same error "] was unexpected at this time."  Apart from `@echo off`, the only command in `pyspark.cmd` is `cmd /V /E /C ""%~dp0pyspark2.cmd" %*"`, which is indecipherable to me.

***It seems odd that the Bash script `pyspark` is set up to run in a Conda environment on Windows.  Is this caused by a fundamental nonsensicality in setting the 3 environment variables above prior to running `pyspark`?***

*And why would running `pyspark.cmd` generate the same error as running the Bash script?*

## Troubleshooting

I tracked the 2nd error message down to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\pyspark2.cmd`.  It is invoked by `pyspark.cmd` and also generates the unexpected `]` error:

```
cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts
psypark2.cmd

   ] was unexpected at this time.
```

To locate the problematic statement, I manually issued each command in `pyspark2.cmd` but did *not* get the same error.  Apart from REM statements, here is `pyspark2.cmd`:

```
REM `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts\pyspark2.cmd`
REM -------------------------------------------------------------
@echo off
rem Figure out where the Spark framework is installed
call "%~dp0find-spark-home.cmd"

call "%SPARK_HOME%\bin\load-spark-env.cmd"
set _SPARK_CMD_USAGE=Usage: bin\pyspark.cmd [options]

rem Figure out which Python to use.
if "x%PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON%"=="x" (
  set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python
  if not [%PYSPARK_PYTHON%] == [] set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=%PYSPARK_PYTHON%
)

set PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python;%PYTHONPATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%

set OLD_PYTHONSTARTUP=%PYTHONSTARTUP%
set PYTHONSTARTUP=%SPARK_HOME%\python\pyspark\shell.py

call "%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit2.cmd" pyspark-shell-main --name "PySparkShell" %*
```

Here is my palette of the above commands, slightly modified to account for the fact that they are executing at an interactive prompt rather than from within a script file:

```
REM ~/tmp/tmp.cmd mirrors pyspark2.cmd
REM ----------------------------------
REM Note that %SPARK_HOME%==
REM "c:\Users\%USERNAME%\anaconda3\pkgs\pyspark-3.2.1-py39haa95532_0\Lib\site-packages\pyspark"

cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts

call "find-spark-home.cmd"

call "%SPARK_HOME%\bin\load-spark-env.cmd"
set _SPARK_CMD_USAGE=Usage: bin\pyspark.cmd [options]

rem Figure out which Python to use.
REM Manually skipped this cuz %PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON%=="python"
if "x%PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON%"=="x" (
  set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python
  if not [%PYSPARK_PYTHON%] == [] set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=%PYSPARK_PYTHON%
)

REM Manually skipped these two cuz they already prefix %PYTHONPATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python;%PYTHONPATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%

set OLD_PYTHONSTARTUP=%PYTHONSTARTUP%
set PYTHONSTARTUP=%SPARK_HOME%\python\pyspark\shell.py

call "%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit2.cmd" pyspark-shell-main --name "PySparkShell" %*
```

The final statement above generates the following error:

```
Error: pyspark does not support any application options.
```

It is odd that `pyspark2.cmd` generates the unexpected `]` error while manually running each statement generates the above "applications options" error.

## Update 2023-07-19

Over the past week, I have *sometimes* been able to get the Spark prompt shown in the Annex below.  Other times, I get the dreaded `] was unexpected at this time.`  It doesn't matter whether or not I start from a virgin Anaconda prompt.  For both outcomes (Spark prompt vs. "unexpected ]"), the series of commands are:

```
(base) C:\Users\User.Name> conda activate py39
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name> set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name> set PYSPARK_PYTHON=python
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name> set PYTHONPATH=c:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\pkgs\pyspark-3.2.1-py39haa95532_0\Lib\site-packages
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name> pyspark
```

## Update 2023-07-22

Due to the unrepeatable outcomes of issuing `pyspark`, I returned to troubleshooting by issuing each command in each invoked script.  Careful bookkeeping was needed to keep track of the arguments `%*` in each script.  The order of invocation is:

- `pyspark.cmd` calls `pyspark2.cmd`
- `pyspark2.cmd` calls `spark-submit2.cmd`
- `spark-submit2.cmd` executes `java`

The final `java` command is:

```
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts> ^
"%RUNNER%" -Xmx128m ^
-cp "%LAUNCH_CLASSPATH%" org.apache.spark.launcher.Main ^
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit pyspark-shell-main ^
--name "PySparkShell" > %LAUNCHER_OUTPUT%
```

It generates the class-not-found error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
```

Here are the environment variables:

```
%RUNNER% = java
%LAUNCH_CLASSPATH% = c:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\pkgs\pyspark-3.2.1-py39haa95532_0\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\jars\*
%LAUNCHER_OUTPUT% = C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-class-launcher-output-22633.txt
```

The RUNNER variable actually has two trailing spaces, and the quoted "%RUNNER%" invocation causes "java  " to be unrecognized, so I removed the quotes.

## Annex: `pyspark` output from *1st* run (not 2nd run)

```
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name>pyspark
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jul  5 2023, 21:22:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/C:/Users/User.Name/anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-3.2.1-py39haa95532_0/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
23/07/07 17:49:58 WARN Shell: Did not find winutils.exe: {}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.fileNotFoundException(Shell.java:548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getHadoopHomeDir(Shell.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBin(Shell.java:592)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:689)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDurationHelper(Configuration.java:1886)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1846)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1819)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
        util.ShutdownHookManager$HookEntry.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.java:304)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:898)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHomeInner(Shell.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:439)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:516)
        ... 22 more
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/07/07 17:50:00 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.2.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.9.17 (main, Jul  5 2023 21:22:06)
Spark context Web UI available at http://HOST-NAME:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1688766602995).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> 23/07/07 17:50:17 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
```

Some of these messages may be innocuous.  I found *some* of them also at
[this page](https://medium.com/@divya.chandana/easy-install-pyspark-in-anaconda-e2d427b3492f)
about installing PySpark in Anaconda (specifically step 4, "Test Spark Installation"):

- That page also had the messages about illegal reflective access
- It did not have my long stack trace due to the file-not found exception pertaining to Hadoop Home being unset
- It did, however, have the same message "Unable to load native-hadoop library"
- It didn't have the final warning "ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize"

After the passage of time and switching to another location and Wi-Fi network I go the following further messages:

```
23/07/07 19:25:30 WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:1005)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$heartbeater$1(Executor.scala:212)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.Heartbeater$$anon$1.run(Heartbeater.scala:46)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        ... 12 more
23/07/07 19:25:40 WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:1005)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$heartbeater$1(Executor.scala:212)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.Heartbeater$$anon$1.run(Heartbeater.scala:46)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        ... 12 more
23/07/07 19:25:50 WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:1005)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$heartbeater$1(Executor.scala:212)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.Heartbeater$$anon$1.run(Heartbeater.scala:46)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        ... 12 more
23/07/07 19:26:00 WARN Executor: Issue communicating with driver in heartbeater
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:1005)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$heartbeater$1(Executor.scala:212)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2019)
        at org.apache.spark.Heartbeater$$anon$1.run(Heartbeater.scala:46)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:259)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        ... 12 more
23/07/07 19:26:05 WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored message: HeartbeatResponse(false)
23/07/07 19:26:05 WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored message: HeartbeatResponse(false)
23/07/07 19:26:05 WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored message: HeartbeatResponse(false)
23/07/07 19:26:05 WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored message: HeartbeatResponse(false)
```

Comment: Don't do `set PYTHONPATH=c:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\pkgs\pyspark-3.2.1-py39haa95532_0\Lib\site-packages` a) it should not be neccessary b) it is not the correct directory, that should reside within the folder of your env, not in `pkgs`

Comment: Can you verify that `python` does actually point to the python within your environment?

Comment: Are you using the `anaconda command prompt` or `anaconda powershell propmt`

Comment: @FlyingTeller: Thanks! Not setting PYTHONPATH before issuing `pyspark` *or* `pyspark.cmd` seems to have gotten me back to the Spark prompt, as shown in the Annex of my posted question.  Unfortunately, all the error messages show as well. Issuing `where python` yields `C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\python.exe` followed by `C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`.  The 1st path takes precedence and correctly points to the *py39* environment. I clarified in my posted question that I am using the Anaconda prompt, not the powershell.

Comment: @FlyingTeller: Did you want to post your 1st comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlyingTeller's answer was definitely "a must know" in order to get
PySpark working.  For the error message that is the subject line of this question,
however, the cause is more insidious and obscure (so much so that it's
no wonder I haven't found anything about it online).

## Tracking down the cause: Trailing spaces in CMD variable assignments

I found the cause while trying to follow up on FlyingTeller's helpful
advice on installing Hadoop and WinUtils.  After obtaining these from
the GitHub site that he recommended, I had to set the following three
variables at the Conda shell prompt, then issue `pyspark`:

```
> set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python
> set PYSPARK_PYTHON=python
> set HADOOP_HOME=c:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1
> pyspark
```

The `2.7.1` folder above contains the `bin` folder that contains `winutils.exe`.  I had captured the exact text above in a manual journal text file,
including indents and ">" prompts.   I used Vim's blockwise Visual
mode (Ctrl+V) to select the four lines into the system clipboard,
starting from the first "s".  Blockwise Visual mode causes the shorter
lines to be right padded with spaces so that they are the same length
as the longest (3rd) line.  All these trailing spaces become part of
the string that is assigned to PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON and
PYSPARK_PYTHON above.  Somewhere the nesting of scripts, these
trailing spaces result in a series of (likely unintended) invocations
that end in the error message "] was unexpected at this time".

The error *doesn't* occur when the variables are set to the strings
*without* trailing spaces.  I had no idea to even look at the
possibility of trailing spaces as the cause for the error, since I'm more used to Bash, where trailing spaces are ignored in variable assignments.

## The solution

**In Vim, Use Visual mode:** In Vim, trailing spaces can be avoided in
the selection process by using Visual mode (V) instead of blockwise
Visual mode.  In selecting multiple lines, however, that would capture
the prompt symbols ">" and indentations that prefix each line.  To
avoid this, I would have capture commands in my text file Journal
without the ">" prompts.  Thus, context is sacrificed, which can be
confusing when showing a series of commands across different
environment.

In the above code, for example, initial commands issued at the
*CMD/Conda* prompt culminate in the invocation of PySpark, which might
be followed by commands issued at a resulting PySpark/Python prompt.
Capturing the prompt character with the series of commands to be
issued gives a clear indication that the interpreter changes partway
through the list of commands.

**Copy each command separately, avoiding trailing spaces:** Another
alternative to using Vim's blockwise Visual mode to copy commands is
to Vim-"yank" each line into the system clipboard, from the 1st letter
to the end of the line.  It is done for each line individually, so it
quickly gets tedious.

**Use quotes around CMD variable assignments:** The [best
solution](https://superuser.com/a/274827/767015) that found was to use
quotes around the variable assignments so that trailing spaces are
ignored:

```
> set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python"
> set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=python"
> set "HADOOP_HOME=c:\Users\User.Name\AppDta\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
> pyspark
```

This way, Vim's blockwise Visual mode can still be used to copy
multiple lines into the clipboard while avoiding prompt characters
and indentation spaces.

## Eliminating the rest of the errors

**WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library**
The following links indicate that this is an innocuous warning,
with the perplexing caveat that I/O on Windows is only guaranteed
to be correct if things are built from scratch.  As I am not a
developer, I felt that I wasn't prepared to take that on.

- https://sparkbyexamples.com/hadoop/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning/?expand_article=1
- https://lists.apache.org/thread/hk0rs1gwjyv5x89890f1hy5brpdc4v8r

Apparently, warnings can be suppressed via
[log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673948), but I didn't
explore that.

**The exception for non-existence of "file:/tmp/spark-events"**
To solve this, I created the following folders:

- %SPARK_HOME%\conf
- C:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\envs\py39\PySparkLogs

I then created the following file:

```
# %SPARK_HOME%/conf/spark-defaults.conf
#--------------------------------------
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir C:\\User\\User.Name\\anaconda3\\envs\\py39\\PySparkLogs
park.history.fs.logDirectory C:\\User\\User.Name\\anaconda3\\envs\\py39\\PySparkLogs
```

Sources of information from which the above solution was synthesized:

- https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/how-to-install-and-run-pyspark-on-windows/?expand_article=1
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeEcWFRBqnU

Note that `%SPARK_HOME%` was not set at the Conda prompt.  I relied on
partially successful attempts at getting to the PySpark prompt in the
past few weeks, then querying and recording the environment variable
`SPARK_HOME`:

```
>>> print(os. environ. get("SPARK_HOME"))
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark
```

I definitely didn't want to be explicitly setting unnecessary
variables because it might be incompatible with how package
installers would set them.  *FlyingTeller's* correction on my
setting of `PYTHONPATH` made this abundantly clear.

**Cannot run program ... `winutils.exe`: Access denied**
While the above eliminated the exception for the non-existence of
"file:/tmp/spark-events", it didn't succeed in entering PySpark,
apparently due to error in initializing "SparkContext", in turn due
to inability to run `wintuils.exe`.  The cause is access denial, but to
what was unclear:

```
23/07/28 14:01:12 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1\bin\winutils.exe": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

Using Cygwin's Bash, I found that none of the files
`c:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1\bin\*.exe` had execute
permission, so fix that.  This eliminated all of the errors and
warnings that had me concerned:

```
# Using Cygwin's Bash
$ chmod u+x /c/Users/User.Name/AppData/Local/Hadoop/2.7.1/bin/*.exe

REM At the Conda prompt
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name> set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python"
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name> set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=python"
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name> set "HADOOP_HOME=c:%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name> pyspark
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jul  5 2023, 21:22:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/C:/Users/User.Name/anaconda3/envs/py39/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/07/28 15:05:19 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.2.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.9.17 (main, Jul  5 2023 21:22:06)
Spark context Web UI available at http://Laptop-Hostname:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1690571121168).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> 23/07/28 15:05:35 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
>>>
```

**`ProcfsMetricsGetter`: Exception when trying to compute pagesize**
This is the final line in the output immediately above.  On Windows,
it is "expected behaviour" (as they say).  It is innocuous, according
to [Wing Yew Poon](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33001)
(who I would probably know if I was a developer) and quoted
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257377) in [this
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841245/2153235).

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to do

```
set PYTHONPATH=c:%HOMEPATH%\anaconda3\pkgs\pyspark-3.2.1-py39haa95532_0\Lib\site-packages
```

and I would even advice against it. If `pyspark` uses the correct python executable, then it should also use the correct `site-packages`. Additionally `pkgs` is the wrong location to point to anyway. Briefly, `conda` downloads and extracts a package to `pkgs` and then actually "installs" it into your env's directory structure, usually by creating a link (in which case both locations would share the same files), but not neccessarily and you shouldn't rely on it.

For the `HADOOP_HOME` issue, you need to set that environment variable as well to point to the directory that contains `winutils.exe`. From https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/WindowsProblems :

> You can fix this problem in two ways
>
> 1. Install a full native windows Hadoop version. The ASF does not currently (September 2015) release such a version; releases are
>    available externally.
> 2. Or: get the `WINUTILS.EXE` binary from a Hadoop redistribution. There is a repository of this for some Hadoop versions on
>    [github](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils).
>
> Then
>
> 1. Set the environment variable `%HADOOP_HOME%` to point to the directory above the BIN dir containing `WINUTILS.EXE`.
> 2. Or: run the Java process with the system property hadoop.home.dir set to the home directory.

Comment: Thanks! I pointed others to your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73823644/#comment135320708_76552980).  I will work through the Hadoop portion of your answer. For the time being, however, I am looking for PySpark examples to check the functionality of Spark in the absence of Hadoop, e.g., perhaps some of the code [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/install-pyspark-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook) or [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark-tutorial).