# Hadoop_instalation: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-native-library

> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/happyhadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
>       It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
>       17/04/30 21:30:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>       Starting namenodes on [localhost]
>       happyhadoop@localhost's password:
>       localhost: namenode running as process 13997. Stop it first.
>       happyhadoop@localhost's password:
>       localhost: datanode running as process 14153. Stop it first.
>       Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
>       happyhadoop@0.0.0.0's password:
>       0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 14432. Stop it first.
>       Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/happyhadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
>       It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
>       17/04/30 21:30:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Can someone please help me with this warning?

Comment: What were you trying to do, please provide more information about the intended action so you can receive the appropriate help.

Comment: I'm currently configuring hadoop on a server running Ubuntu 14.04LTS OS, When I run start-dfs.sh or stop-dfs.sh, I get the following error which i shared above comment

Comment: Configuring Hadoop is a very tricky process. I suggest you follow carefully through [Hadoop: Setting up a Single Node Cluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html). The simplest way however will be to download [Cloudera CDH](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/cdh/5-11-0.html), which comes with Hadoop core and other parts of the Hadoop ecosystem like Hive, Pig, Impala and Sqoop installed.

Comment: StackGuard is an extension run automatically by the compiler to prevent buffer overflow. Curious why the Hadoop library is disabling it. Try running the commands suggested, i.e. `execstack -c` to fix the library. More info on that command can be seen here. [Package: execstack](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/execstack)

Comment: @Ekaba, okie..Let me cross verify once all the setting

Comment: @EkabaBisong, configuration done properly only..after executing this command hadoop liberary is disabling. it is coming out of the process and throwing this error : WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Comment: The following thread might prove useful, please check it.
[Hadoop “Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform” warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning?rq=1)