# how do you enable webhdfs?

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

I am trying to use webhdfs.

I have place these lines to hdfs-site.xml file:

```
<property> 
    <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name> 
    <value>true</value> 
</property>
```

I did a stop-all.sh and start-all.sh on hadoop cluster.

I am trying to see if I can use webhdfs by this url call:

```
http://<myserver>:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/root/output/?op=LISTSTATUS
```

if I just do:

```
http://<myserver>:50070
```

I get hadoop over view page.

So, I can remotely access my server at port 50070 but webhdfs piece does not seem to be working. I would like to be able to access hdfs using rest api calls, to either read or put files.

any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Experienced similar problems and finally found a solutions here on SA: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879303/1178902)

Comment: I guess the file name should be `hdfs-site.xml` instead of `htfs-site.xml`