# Hadoop 3.1.2 Failed to retrieve data from /webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS: Server Error

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, namenode

I'm using hadoop 3.1.2 and jdk-12.0.1 operating on Pseudo-Distributed mode. So far from the command line every thing seems to be working normal I can upload files retrieve from hdfs and local.
For some reason when I open the namenode which is actually accede via http://ip:9870 and navigate to utilities/Browse Directory, the browser opens and this is what is highlighted "Failed to retrieve data from /webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS: Server Error"
I know this question have been asked before [Error "Failed to retrieve data from /webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS: Server Error" when using hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735869/error-failed-to-retrieve-data-from-webhdfs-v1-op-liststatus-server-error-wh)  but the answer did not satisfy that's why I have reopen the case.

```
hdfs-site.xml 
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>dfs.replication</name>
 <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/debian/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/debian/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

my output of `netstat -ntlp`incase if something is missing

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9864            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6033/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.250:9000      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5935/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9866            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6033/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9867            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6033/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9868            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6196/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9870            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5935/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46613         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6033/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have found out Hadoop doesn't support Java 12 (as of 07/02/2019).

The wiki 
[Hadoop Java Versions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions)
 describes the currently supported Java versions.

To see when Java 11 LTS is supported you can track this JIRA.

- [HADOOP-15338](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15338) Support Java 11 LTS in Hadoop

Comment: Noted, thanks for this valuable information it's very helpful.

Comment: still hadoop doesn't support jdk-11.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I final resolved the problem I hard to change the Java Version and use `1.8.0_201` 
this resolved my problem. Every thing is working as expected, a quick note to any one how is going to run in to this problem don't use java 9,10,11,12 with hadoop they don't play well
you will get all sort of strange behavior. At list by the time i'm writing this :) that's how it stands. Port 8042 is now up and I can access the browser as well http://ip:8042