# No Hadoop in Java Library Path Cloudera. When submitted a Java Job

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, kerberos

I am trying to run a java program. The Java program is used to log the data in Hbase. While i  am running the code i am facing the issue with no hadoop in the java lib path.

Following is the error

```
org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Failed to load native-hadoop 
with error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hadoop in java.library.path
```

It also throws the error regarding the kebrors athuentication

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil.hasKerberosTicket
(Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z
```

Is kerboros is thrown because of the absence of hadoop or anything different

How to Export the path to the java lib. I am running in cloudera.

Comment: Find this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning

Comment: And you need to run `kinit` followed by `klist` to check you have a Kerberos ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake i have done is submitted as a java program. There are lot of dependencies that are not loaded as we submitted as java program. Java classPath doesnt have hadoop and hbase configuration dependencies.

So please **submit the job as a hadoop job**. So that all the dependencies are available now.