# Shutting down NameNode at ubuntu/127.0.1.1

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, namenode

my system composed of :

1. Ubuntu x32 bit (i386.iso)
2. hadoop-1.2.1
3. java 1.8.0_171

so when i run this command :

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

i get those errors :

WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform

....

SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ubuntu/127.0.1.1

Comment: You are not shutting down the namenode instead you are formatting it.
And regarding WARNING you can ignore it... or refer previously answered questions... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You should remove `127.0.1.1` lines from your /etc/hosts before starting to install Hadoop