# why hdfs dfs commands are stuck?

Tags: hadoop

I have recently installed hadoop 3.2.0 on Linux and trying to issue commands like `hdfs dfs -ls /`. But I don't see any output at all, it seems like stuck somewhere.

I also get the warning message:

> 'Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable'

But that is all. Please let me know how to resolve this.

```
$hadoop fs -ls /
```

no output, command stuck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)

Comment: Are you running all necessary daemons (NameNode, DataNodes)? What do you see if you do "hdfs dfs -mkdir /blah"?