# Why isn't the hadoop fs command executable to create directory?

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I have started hadoop namenode and datanode.But I can't to create directory when I execute the "hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/root/test".

It have told me "19/08/01 14:34:49 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable".

What should I do?Thanks!

Comment: That's not an error. Did you get another error? Are you sure the folder isn't created?

Comment: how did you verify it failed? Was there any other errors other than this Warning?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you added HADOOP_HOME in your ~/.bashrc file? Is $HADOOP_HOME/bin in your path?
If not then add the following two lines in the ~/.bashrc file. Change the 
fullPathToFolderWhereHadoopResides with the folder where hadoop is.

```sh
export HADOOP_HOME=/fullPathToFolderWhereHadoopResides
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

All the best.

Comment: Operate like my teacher,I have added Hadoop  environment variable in /etc/profile file.

Comment: Ok great. Your teacher must have given you full instructions. Just to make sure ... what are the output of these? Do you see Hadoop folders there? "echo $PATH" and "echo $HADOOP_HOME"?

Comment: I tried to query in BaiDu.A blog have told me "Glibc's version is low."   Then I tried to use yum tool to install the Glibc. Then I  tried to use "hadoop fs" . Command was executed correctly.But It's still tell me that message."WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable"

Comment: Execuse me! Could it be that its current version is too low?

Comment: Could I get your Facebook?

Comment: See this answer why got the Warning if you are concerned about it ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning

Comment: I think I have already known this reason.Thank you very much!