# Spark: use native hadoop library locally

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I start spark applications for test from intellij. I always see this message:

```
WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Will I get any improvments if I use this native library? (I have a MacOS)

Comment: This was already clarified here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning

Comment: I already saw this link, however it explains the "how" and not the "why" (which is my question)