# how to fix unable to get Charset 'cp720' for property 'sun.stdout.encoding', using default windows-1256 and continuing.?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

the command line is always showing me this problem when I am trying to start spark. I tried to run it from Jupiter notebook and from command line. it gives the same problem.

```
Unable to get Charset 'cp720' for property 'sun.stdout.encoding', using default windows-1256 and continuing. 
WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform.
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
```

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSBkb.png)

Comment: check environment variable values and for warning https://stackoverflow.com/a/24927214/7130689