# Running delta lake in python and Debian as standalone spark

Tags: python, pyspark, delta-lake

I want to use a delta lake in python. I installed spark as stand alone and anaconda in Debian 11.6.

The code that I try to run delta lake is:

```
import pyspark
from delta import *

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

But the above code arise this error:

```
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/bin/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3/jars/ivy-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml

Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/boss/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/boss/.ivy2/jars
io.delta#delta-core_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-290d27e6-7e29-475f-81b5-1ab1331508fc;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.2.0 in central
    found io.delta#delta-storage;2.2.0 in central
    found org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.8 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 272ms :: artifacts dl 10ms
    :: modules in use:
    io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.2.0 from central in [default]
    io.delta#delta-storage;2.2.0 from central in [default]
    org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.8 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   3   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   3   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-290d27e6-7e29-475f-81b5-1ab1331508fc
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 3 already retrieved (0kB/11ms)

23/01/24 04:10:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: What problem? What error? I see some warnings, including one about already having retrieved the data you requested.

Comment: @tripleee.@tripleee .Tanks. Is it not create problem in the continue? How can solve this warnings?

Answer (score 0):

This is really not an error but:

- debug information about fetching the necessary dependencies
- warning about inability to find a library with the native code, but it doesn't prevent from working, just could be a bit slower because it uses the Java code.  It could be solved by either installing necessary libraries or adding them to the search path. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning) or [this article](https://sparkbyexamples.com/hadoop/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning/) for instructions