# Hot to get rid of 'Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform' with local Spark and Delta Lake

Tags: java, hadoop, pyspark, delta-lake, java.library.path

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19943766/947012) and tried every single answer except rebuilding Hadoop (which is failing with endless errors so far). My hope is that the binaries from the official Hadoop [distribution](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.3.4/hadoop-3.3.4.tar.gz) will do, but I can't make it work.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y default-jdk
RUN pip install pyspark==3.3.2 delta-spark==2.2.0
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
ENV HADOOP_HOME /app/hadoop-3.3.4
ENV HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/app/hadoop-3.3.4/lib/native
ENV HADOOP_PREFIX /app/hadoop-3.3.4
ENV HADOOP_COMMON_HOME /app/hadoop-3.3.4
ENV HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR /app/hadoop-3.3.4/lib/native
ENV HADOOP_CONF_DIR /app/hadoop-3.3.4/etc/hadoop
ENV HADOOP_HDFS_HOME /app/hadoop-3.3.4
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native
ENV JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH /app/hadoop-3.3.4/lib/native
WORKDIR /app
```

main.py:

```py
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from delta import configure_spark_with_delta_pip

builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("my") \
    .config('spark.sql.extensions', 'io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension') \
    .config('spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog', 'org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog')

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

```
% tar -zxf hadoop-3.3.4.tar.gz
% docker build . -t mydelta
% docker run -it --rm -v `pwd`:/app mydelta bash

% python main.py
...
23/02/25 02:13:34 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
...
```

Functionally it works well, but I would like to get rid of the warning.

```
% printenv | grep "HADOOP\|JAVA"
HADOOP_OPTS=/app/hadoop-3.3.4/lib/native
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/app/hadoop-3.3.4
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/app/hadoop-3.3.4/etc/hadoop
HADOOP_HOME=/app/hadoop-3.3.4
HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/app/hadoop-3.3.4
JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/hadoop-3.3.4/lib/native
HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=/app/hadoop-3.3.4/lib/native
HADOOP_PREFIX=/app/hadoop-3.3.4

% ls -l $HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR
total 166800
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root       192 Jul 29  2022 examples
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1507316 Jul 29  2022 libhadoop.a
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root root        18 Jul 29  2022 libhadoop.so -> libhadoop.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    803040 Jul 29  2022 libhadoop.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1741256 Jul 29  2022 libhadooppipes.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    754382 Jul 29  2022 libhadooputils.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    551572 Jul 29  2022 libhdfs.a
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root root        16 Jul 29  2022 libhdfs.so -> libhdfs.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    333656 Jul 29  2022 libhdfs.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 106649802 Jul 29  2022 libhdfspp.a
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root root        18 Jul 29  2022 libhdfspp.so -> libhdfspp.so.0.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  44450288 Jul 29  2022 libhdfspp.so.0.1.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10010090 Jul 29  2022 libnativetask.a
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root root        22 Jul 29  2022 libnativetask.so -> libnativetask.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   3980832 Jul 29  2022 libnativetask.so.1.0.0

% ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.31-13+deb11u5) 2.31

% ldd $HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd405a5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f36012ea000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f36012c8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f36010f3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f360151b000)

% file libhadoop.so.1.0.0
libhadoop.so.1.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=30ce002bb1ee648ac42090156300dbf4f5f9c1c4, with debug_info, not stripped

% objdump -f libhadoop.so.1.0.0
libhadoop.so.1.0.0:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000150:
HAS_SYMS, DYNAMIC, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000006bd0
```

Can you spot if anything is wrong with my libhadoop.so.1.0.0?
What else can I try?

Comment: Does your code work? You can ignore that warning

Comment: @OneCricketeer, yes, as mentioned in the question, the code works. If I understand correctly, there is a performance benefit of using native libraries, isn't it?

Comment: Sure, but the included ones are built for 32bit - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer `file libhadoop.so.1.0.0:`
`libhadoop.so.1.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)...`

Comment: Yes, I see that from your post... I have not done any of this in Docker, so I am really sure. You may need to modify `spark-env.sh` file