# Hadoop: start-dfs.sh gives WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes

Tags: hadoop

I am new to data science and Hadoop, I have successfully installed Hadoop on my mac device as per tutorial "https://youtu.be/_btD1nDY6hk". However upon trying to start dfs or running
`start-dfs.sh`
I get this error message: "***2023-03-23 22:49:30,839 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable***"
I doubt its because of java version thats preinstalled on my device with installation of android studio. Our professor had recommended to use java 8.
Is the issue due to java version or some other cause? can anybody please help me?

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning that you can ignore, see the related questions linked below.

Comment: Thankyou, its working now . I am trying this as provided by our lecturer now "hdfs dfs -put LICENSE.txt /user/hduser/input/" as he had said its an example folder that already exists in the system but gives me this message "put: `LICENSE.txt': No such file or directory", Ben sir can you provide me some references for getting started with Hadoop?

Comment: You should use Java 11 with latest Hadoop. But error means you're running the command in the wrong folder. Has nothing to do with Hadoop since it's referring to local files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hadoop "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning)

Comment: yes it has help and worked, thankyou