# Issue with starting hadoop using "start-dfs" command on MacBook M1 and tried running "start-dfs.sh" file manually but it is giving following errors

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Here is the error Log I'm seeing on my screen when I execute start-dfs.sh file by changing into Hadoop installed location:

**(base) ramc@Rams-MBP ~ % start-dfs.sh**

Starting namenodes on [Rams-MBP.attlocal.net]
Rams-MBP.attlocal.net: WARNING: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.4/libexec/logs does not exist.

Creating.
Starting datanodes

Starting secondary namenodes [Rams-MBP.attlocal.net]

2023-06-01 11:47:52,074 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

I've tried starting hadoop manually and also using start-dfs command but nothing works. I set Export and path in .bash_profile sucessfully.

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. They should not prevent the execution.

Comment: Ohhh Yeah, those are warnings. My bad !
But still I'm unable to go to next step. I'm executing "hdfs dfs -mkdir /data" command on my mac terminal. But it's giving me the warning "2023-06-01 12:15:20,090 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: `/data': Input/output error" instead of creating the directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-warning